# Why doesn't my code produce a polygon when the coordinates are correctly generated?

Tags: java, polygon

Currently, I've created a code that would generate the coordinates of a quadrilateral and inserted them into a list to generate the corners of the quad to make a polygon

I've currently generated the following code and the system.out.prints lets me know what coordinates were generated I've plotted them on a graph and I was satisfied with the plot that it generated

HOwever this is the code:

```
   package endOfYearGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class arrow {
    double theta;
    int x;
    int y;
    int horizontal = 70;
    int vertical = 10;
    int originalX = 50;
    int originalY = 800-50;
    public arrow() {
        this.theta = Math.PI/4.0;
        this.x = originalX;
        this.y = originalY;
    }

    public void rotateRight() {
        this.theta = this.theta - 0.1;
    }
    public void rotateLeft() {
        this.theta = this.theta + 0.1;
    }

    public void drawArrow(Graphics2D win) {
        win.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //x's of the rectangular arrows
        int bottomRightX = (int)(this.x+horizontal*Math.cos(theta));
        int topRightX = (int)(bottomRightX-Math.sin(this.theta)*vertical);
        int topLeftX = (int)(this.x-Math.sin(this.theta)*vertical);

        //y's of the rectangular arrows
        int bottomRightY = (int)(this.y-Math.sin(this.theta)*horizontal);
        int topRightY =  (int)(bottomRightY-vertical*Math.cos(this.theta)) ;
        int topLeftY = (int)(this.y-vertical/Math.cos(this.theta));
        int Xs[] = {this.x, bottomRightX, topRightX, topLeftX};
        int Ys[] = {this.y, bottomRightY, topRightY, topLeftY};
        int Xss[] = {this.x, bottomRightX, topRightX, topLeftX,this.x};
        int Yss[] = {this.y, bottomRightY, topRightY, topLeftY,this.y};
        win.setColor(Color.RED);
        win.drawPolygon(Xs,Ys,4);
        win.fillPolygon(Xss, Yss, 4);
        System.out.println("0000 bottomrightx = "+bottomRightX);
        System.out.println("toprightx= "+topRightX);
        System.out.println("topleftx= " + topLeftX);
        System.out.println("bottomleftx = "+this.x);
        System.out.println("bottomrighty = "+ bottomRightY );
        System.out.println("toprighty = "+topRightY);
        System.out.println("toplefty = "+topLeftY);
        System.out.println("bottomlefty = "+this.y);
    }

}
```

But it generates no polygon at all!

I was wondering if there was something wrong with this?

Comment: Need the whole class to see what's up since you are referencing theta, vertical etc and we have no idea what those values are.

Comment: also helpful to see the output - and I wonder if division is correct in `vertical/Math.cos(this.theta)`  and more that *"the coordinates are correctly generated"* (if that really is the case, then the error *must* be in `drawPolygon()` which we have no clue what it does, but its name)

Comment: @Benson99 Uploaded the code

Comment: a typical mistake might be that the polygon is one sided and only visible from the other side(i.e. you might have passed the corners in the wrong order) but its hard to say just by this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never invokes `drawArrow`. If it did, it would draw the polygon. Here's the output:

```
0000 bottomrightx = 99
toprightx= 91
topleftx= 42
bottomleftx = 50
bottomrighty = 700
toprighty = 692
toplefty = 735
bottomlefty = 750
```

And here's the result in a 1024x768 window:

[image: Large gray image with spec of red in the bottom right]